# How to add value to a Pointer in Memory?

Tags: c#, winforms, memory

i can **change** Pointer's value like this:

`WriteMemory("Tutorial-x86_64.exe+0073EEA8,aa8,198,c", "float", "25");`

But i need to add the value "25" to the pointer..

i hope you can help me :)

Comment: If you're manually writing memory in C# then something somewhere went terribly wrong. What are you trying to achieve? Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) or is it just an experiment?

Comment: Well we can say it is an experiment.. i am trying this in cheat engine's tutorial.exe at the moment and i would like to do the same thing in another application/game

Comment: so is there any chance that you can help me? :) ( cuz i've tried to figure this out myself for days :((((((((((( )

Comment: Well, are you trying to add 25 to the value of the pointer (i.e it's pointing to a value `50` in memory and you're trying to add to that), or are you trying to add 25 to the pointer address (i.e offset the pointer by 25 bytes)?

Comment: i am trying to add 25 to pointer's value.

Comment: Ok, you're basic operations are read and write memory. So to add 25 to a value in memory, we need to first read that value, add 25 to the read value, and then write our modified value back to the memory location. In your case, probably `float value = ReadMemory(/*I don't know the params*/); value += 25; WriteValue("Tutorial-x86...", "float", value.ToString());`

Comment: @MindSwipe 
Like this?
```float value = mem.ReadFloat("Tutorial.exe + 0073EEA8, aa8, 198, c", "float"); 


value += 25;


mem.WriteMemory("Tutorial.exe+0073EEA8,aa8,198,c", "float", value.ToString());```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231303/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-gorkido).

Comment: If you are using a third party library you should state such in the question, with a tag if possible. C# can use pointers in unsafe code, but that is probably not what you are after in this case.